# Example of adding relationship to pyramid_blogr models

Tags: python, pyramid

Working through the tutorial at http://pyramid-blogr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and would like to add a relationship between the user and entry models and then be able to have that FK field populated when a new post is added.

Here is what I have so far...

**entry.py**

```
...
class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    body = Column(UnicodeText, default=u'')
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    edited = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))

    user = relationship("User", backref=backref('entries'))
...
```

**user.py**

```
...
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    last_logged = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    entries = relationship("Entry", order_by="entry.id", backref="user_id")

...
```

I'm assuming forms.py would also need a modification to pass the user_id as a hidden field but I may not be thinking about that correctly.

Comment: If you have not yet worked through the Quick Tutorial, I would recommend doing that first. There is a lesson on [19: Databases Using SQLAlchemy](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/databases.html) which may be helpful in identifying all the necessary bits and pieces. The lessons in the Quick Tutorial build upon each other in succession, so be warned that skipping earlier lessons and trying to run a specific later lesson might not work.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and am taking a look at several tutorials. If anyone else can provide a simple example of how this would be accomplished within the existing codebase of pyramid_blogr tutorial i would still be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian,

When you declare a relationship like "entries" (like you did in your snippets)

and define a foreign key, you can do something like:

```
user.entries.append(entry)
```

And your foreign key will be auto populated and your newly created object will get added to session - you do NOT want to pass user_id as form parameter to your model - this would be unsafe operation as one user could save the entry for someone else.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html?highlight=append#one-to-many

Here is the section of sqlalchemy docs that illustrates it.